# Make calls to a Java object running in a existing JVM with PHP

Tags: java, php, servlets, jvm

I am getting into an existing project which implies lots of remote objects communicating together to compute and transfer data.

My goal is to create a web application allowing enduser to input some data and get the results after treatment through the existing distributed application.

Regarding that, I looked for a way to make calls to existing Java objects with PHP, but in most of cases it was about how to create a JVM and instanciate objects directly in PHP, but not accessing to an existing and running JVM.

So, what could be the better way to do that ? I also heard about creating a servlet, but I have no real knowledge about this for the moment, so I am sending a S.O.S in a bottle to the StackOverflow community, hoping someone (and I am sure there is) would have a good answer to that problem :-)

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing what interfaces your distributed application exposes to the world

Comment: PHP cannot talk to Java directly, and vice versa. You'll have to create an API and use that instead. e.g. create a servlet. Expose the Java applet via a Tomcat server and use standard web methods to talk with it. Or if it's all local, create a socket and a messaging format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the java application. You have to add some kind of remote interface to that app, which can then be used by PHP. If you are inexperienced in java, you're out of luck.

One of the options described above is the servlet, which basically means exposing your java app through a REST or SOAP interface. That may or may not be the simplest solution, depending on your java app. If it is a webapp, you're in luck. You can try using JAX-WS to do that. The downside is that such communication comes with an overhead. If your java app is a command line program, you could use an embedded servlet container such as Jetty or try using WSpublish (built into java 6).

You can give Hessian a try. It is a binary web service protocol that supports both PHP and java. I have used it extensively on java-only environments, but it may work in php-java scenario as well. http://hessian.caucho.com/

As you can see, there are plenty of options, but all of them require knowledge and experience in JAVA and cannot be described in one sentence or two.

The easiest java WS example I have seen can be found here:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+javalobby/frontpage+(Javalobby+/+Java+Zone)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try the PHP/Java Bridge project : http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

Comment: That looks interesting ! I am going to look at this, hoping this is a stable and reliable solution :)

Comment: i think it is a reliable and good project. it is documented well. try running the examples and samples code it will give you an idea if the project is usefull for your application. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There's one door into a running java virtual machine: the java management extensions. The door has to be unlocked from the inside, so the application has to offer some managed beans and the jvm has to be started with some parameters.

But once this is setup up properly, then you have an open port where you can read and set data from/on instances or execute methods.

I can't tell exactly how difficult it is to use this connection to the jvm from "other languages", maybe you just have to be able to emulate javas object serialization with php. But it might be offer a solution for your actual problem.